# Use of unresolved identifier sourceApplication Facebook SDK

Tags: ios, swift, facebook

The following code to implement FB login into my app

```
func application(app: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, options: [String :    AnyObject]) -> Bool {
    return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, openURL: url, sourceApplication: sourceApplication, annotation: annotation)
```

However I keep getting two error messages both similar,

"Use of unresolved identifier 'annotation'
"Use of unresolved identifier 'sourceApplication'

I'm not exactly sure what's causing this error but I have a feeling its a bit of code that's been deprecated. Does anyone know what the current alternative is?

[appdelegate.swift](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fdZ7r.png)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I´m using this code in my app delegate and works perfect

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
}

func application(application: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: AnyObject) -> Bool {
     return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, openURL: url, sourceApplication: sourceApplication, annotation: annotation)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a variable name mismatch:

You declare your `UIApplication` as `app` in the first line, but try to reference it by `sourceApplication` in your return statement.  Replace `sourceApplication` with `app`.  Same with `annotation`, change that to `options`:

```
func application(app: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, options: [String :    AnyObject]) -> Bool {
    return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, openURL: url, sourceApplication: app, annotation: options)
```

Comment: Hi JAL thanks for your answer, so I implemented that fix but now I run into a new issue, I keep getting the error 'ambiguous reference to member application'. Would this have to do with the use of 

    [String : AnyObject]

Comment: It shouldn't.  Verify `FBSDKApplicationDelegate` has a function called `application(...)`.

Comment: Here I will edit the post to show you exactly what I have.

Comment: @bananibau5 If you have any additional questions it might be best to ask a new question.